# how to read / copy a tmp file which exists for a very short time

Tags: shell, nginx, debian, tmp, temporary-files

my nginx creates tmp files for requests which are bigger than 16kb. I am trying to read this tmp files but they only exist for a rly short period of time (1ms?). Is there unix command / programm which can help me to read this files before they are gone?

the ngnix warning message looks like

```
a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000001851
```

**EDIT**
i am not in the position to alter the ngnix source code nor am i able to edit the source code of the request origin. I just want to take a look at this files for debugging purpose as i cant imagine what kind of request will bloat up to 16k

Answer (score 3):

In general you'll probably want to get nginx's assistance for this or if that's not possible and it's really important change the source code as Leo suggests.

---

There is one cringe-inducing, wtf-provoking trick which I am mentioning as a curiosity. You can set the append-only mode on the directory. If your filesystem supports it you can say:

```
chattr +a mydir
```

Your process will be able to create stuff inside but not remove it. Then at your leisure you can use `inotify_wait` to monitor the directory for changes. I don't know of any clean ways to remove the files though.

Answer (score -1):

Well you could try parsing the output with something like:

```
stdbuf -oL nginx 2>&1 |
  grep -F --line-buffered \
    "a client request body is buffered to a temporary file" | {
      while read -a line
      cp line[${#line[@]}-1] /dest/path
    }
```

Although you might find that this is too slow and the file is gone before you can copy it.

A better solution might be to use `inotify`. `inotify_wait` as mentioned by cnicutar would work. You could try the following:

```
while true
do
  file=$(inotifywait -e create --format %f -r /var/lib/nginx/body/)
  cp "/var/lib/nginx/body/$file" "/dest/path/$file"
done
```

If you don't get what you are looking for (eg if the files are copied before all the data is written), you could experiment with different events instead of `create`, maybe `close`, `close_write` or `modify`.